# how to display Persian or Arabic characters in javafx scene builder

Tags: javafx, arabic

I have created a javafx application using javafx scene builder to design its interface, when i try to show some Persian or Arabic characters scene builder shows it in disorder mode, for example while i change a label's text to a Persian or Arabic word "اسم" it is writing in disorder mode (from left to right) like "م س ا" (without any space between the characters). I think maybe javafx scene builder doesn't support Persian or Arabic languages but i know there should be some way, so please help me how to do it.

Note: i just want to change the text of my label, button or some other control via double clicking on the control and change its text, so i haven't done any coding.

Kind Regards.

Comment: How about posting your code?

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem and after lots of search with my friend we solved the problem by using bdo tag.
سلام
For more information take a look at this:

http://www.robinlionheart.com/stds/html4/dir

We still have a problem with text inputs, and I was hoping if anybody could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a version of JavaFX with RTL support That is JavaFX 8 (included in JDK8).

Answer (score 0):

> I think maybe javafx scene builder doesn't support Persian or Arabic languages

Yes, this is currently correct.

Support for right to left writing won't be available in JavaFX (and consequently SceneBuilder as it is built on JavaFX), until the JDK8 release (currently scheduled for September, 2013).

You can make use of the [SceneBuilder 1.1 early access previews](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html), to see if the functionality has been added to a late development build.  But, I don't think RTL support is in the current SceneBuilder 1.1 preview builds.

> but i know there should be some way

I do not believe this will be possible until it is supported in the underlying platform.