# How can I render a Farsi or Arabic text with connected glyphs in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, arabic, right-to-left, arabic-support, farsi

I want to display a text with JavaFX. The message is Farsi or Arabic.
However, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/spec/j2d-fonts.html#wp74588), the representation shape of a Farsi or Arabic letter depends on its adjacent letters.

If I build a `TextFlow` with a single `Text` containing the whole message, it is displayed correctly.
But when I split it across multiple `Text`s, the message become broken.

[image]

For instance, the following snippet yields above figure:

```java
public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 48);

        String message = "\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645  \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0643\u0645";
        TextFlow textFlow1 = new TextFlow();
        Text text1 = new Text(message);
        text1.setFont(font);
        textFlow1.getChildren().addAll(text1);

        TextFlow textFlow2 = new TextFlow();
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char ch = message.charAt(i);
            Text text2 = new Text(ch + "");
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                text2.setFill(Color.RED);
            text2.setFont(font);
            textFlow2.getChildren().add(text2);
        }

        VBox box = new VBox(textFlow1, textFlow2);
        box.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 400, 150);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I'm using javafx version 18.0.1 and java 17 on Mac OS.
But the result is same for Linux, as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19762787/14855128

Comment: Thank you @Mehran. I'd seen that post. But I don't get the point that what is the relationship between html tags and javafx `TextFlow`. Do you mean that I should use javafx `WebView`? It is also has its issues and I don't want to use it.

Comment: Here is a comment by Tim Hollowway [here](https://coderanch.com/t/707390/java/arabic-letters-characters-Connected) that may be worth reading. I can't post the comment here because it is too long.

Comment: Many thanks, @SedJ601. I didn't get you. Do you mean that the issue causes because I am using inappropriate font? I conducted the same scenario with the identical font in MS Word and also in html on web browser. Both of them are rendered the text correctly. It seems that the problem is with JavaFX. Isn't it?

Comment: @vahidreza As far as I know JavaFX can use CSS which presents some attributes about language, font, directions , text flow and alignment.

Comment: I'm familiar with CSS in JavaFX. I just checked [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) again but could not find any thing. Could you please check it as well?

Comment: The problem appears to be with `JavaFX`, but Tim offers his possible solutions given the problem. The part I am referring to starts like `There are really 2 factors here. Kerning is the term that refers to adjusting the spacing between letters to make them look better as a unit. `.

Comment: @SedJ601 Could you please explain more about your idea?

Comment: It seems that it is a known bug in javafx and reported [here](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092022), in openjdk bug system.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, it is a known bug and reported in openjdk issue tracking system about 10 years ago (see [here](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092022)). Unfortunately it is marked as low priority.

Therefore, I decided to tackle this issue manually, at this moment (thanks to [@SedJ601](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423906/sedj601) for his inspirational comments). I have to do some magics in the boundaries of `Text`s, if they becomes broken in flow. I think there are two possible solutions:

1. Use [Kashida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashida)
2. Use [arabic presentation forms B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Presentation_Forms-B) which includes all variants of each letter

However, both of these solutions have some issues, specially in case of lam with alef. But the second one looks better.

For example, in the following, I've added two new `TextFlow` with respect to the above solutions into my previous sample code.

```java
public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 48);

        String message = "\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645  \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0643\u0645";
        TextFlow textFlow1 = new TextFlow();
        Text text1 = new Text(message);
        text1.setFont(font);
        textFlow1.getChildren().addAll(text1);

        TextFlow textFlow2 = new TextFlow();
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char ch = message.charAt(i);
            Text text2 = new Text(ch + "");
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                text2.setFill(Color.RED);
            text2.setFont(font);
            textFlow2.getChildren().add(text2);
        }


        List prefixes = Arrays.asList(2,3,4,9,10,11,12);
        List suffixes = Arrays.asList(1, 2,3,8,9,10,11);
        message = "\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645  \u0639\u0644\u064a\u0643\u0645";
        TextFlow textFlow3 = new TextFlow();
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char ch = message.charAt(i);
            String suffix = "", prefix = "";
            if (suffixes.contains(i)) suffix = "\u0640";
            if (prefixes.contains(i)) prefix = "\u0640";
            Text text3 = new Text(prefix + ch + suffix);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                text3.setFill(Color.RED);
            text3.setFont(font);
            textFlow3.getChildren().add(text3);
        }


        TextFlow textFlow4 = new TextFlow();
        message = "\u0627\uFEE0\uFEB4\uFEDf\uFE8e\u0645  \uFECb\uFEDf\uFEF4\uFEDc\uFEE2";
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char ch = message.charAt(i);
            Text text4 = new Text(ch + "");
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                text4.setFill(Color.RED);
            text4.setFont(font);
            textFlow4.getChildren().add(text4);
        }


        VBox box = new VBox(textFlow1, textFlow2, textFlow3, textFlow4);
        box.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 500, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The result looks this:
[image]

In this sample I've generated the final `Text`s by myself. However in the real applications, it needs some computations to find the positions.

Note that the first solutions looks very ugly. It is because of my sample which needs too many Kashidas. It gets better as the number of breaks and corresponding Kashidas decreases.